# Enable JavaScript to use this app" when integrating Web app into Power BI with HTML content tool

Tags: html, powerbi, dashboard, streamlit, azure-webapps

I successfully integrated a web app into Power BI using the HTML content tool. However, I encountered an error stating "Enable JavaScript to use this app." I'm seeking assistance to resolve this issue. Any insights or solutions would be greatly appreciated.

Steps Taken:

- Integrated Azure(Streamlit) web app into Power BI using HTML content.
- Published the Power BI report.
- Accessed the app and encountered the "Enable JavaScript" error.
- Tried enabling JavaScript in the browser settings, but the issue persisted.

Any guidance on resolving this JavaScript-related error would be appreciated. Thank you!